# cell template in angular grid not visible in pdf

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) and want to export the table data in PDF through grid menu.

```
   $scope.gridOptions = {
         enableGridMenu: true,
         columnDefs: [
              {
                name: "Group",
                cellTemplate: '<div ng-if="row.entity.unit_GROUP">{{row.entity.unit_GROUP.description}}</div><div ng-if="!row.entity.unit_GROUP">No Group Assigned</div>'
              }
            ]
        }
```

This is shown in cell but when i eport the pdf through grid menu option.all the data except this group columns is exported and visible in grid.

My question is how can i make the data of grid visible which is shown in conditional cell template in columnDefs.

**EDITL(*added an example*):**

[This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HGukMP27ojhhdj6FTElm?p=preview) can show the problm in which "export all data as pdf" is not showing the column with conditional template(Married);

Comment: If you couldn't achieve this, I would advise adding temporary field that `Married` column that will took.